# Height of a div reduces when inner div has position absolute

Tags: jquery, css

I am having a hard time phrasing the question. I have a `<header>` with a absolute positioned div within it. The problem is, due to it's absolute positioning, the next element is going underneath it. I hope you understand what I mean to say. I have created a [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/j474js6e/1/) to replicate the issue.

My question is, how can I clear the height so that the next element doesn't get underneath the absolute positioned div? Here is a screenshot of the problem..

[image]

And, here is the HTML and the CSSs I have tried. Any help on this is appreciated.

```css
.site-header{
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
.site-header::after{
  content:"";
  height:1px;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  clear:both;
}
.top-nav{
  background: #222222;
  padding:10px;
  display:block;
}
.main-nav-wrapper{
  position:absolute;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  padding:40px 0;
  height:20px;
  width:100%;
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<header class="site-header">
  <nav class="top-nav">
  
  </nav>
  <div class="main-nav-wrapper">
    <nav class="main-nav"></nav>
  </div>
</header>
<section class="content">
  <h1>SECTION HEADING</h1>
  <p>
  

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin tortor ante, dictum sed volutpat sit amet, accumsan at urna. Vestibulum congue, nulla a mollis dapibus, ex ex iaculis velit, vel lacinia elit justo at erat. Nulla at rutrum ipsum. Integer et tortor vitae ligula porttitor feugiat. Quisque quis nulla in tortor eleifend aliquet. Nunc nec dui nisl. Integer ultricies ullamcorper nisl, ut imperdiet augue luctus id. Proin lobortis non nibh ut accumsan. Sed mi ligula, suscipit non commodo vitae, facilisis at sapien. Praesent luctus arcu tincidunt felis consectetur volutpat. Duis tellus risus, auctor elementum bibendum at, varius vel massa. Etiam tristique sit amet nisi a vestibulum. Aenean mollis suscipit nunc. Vestibulum volutpat diam ut metus interdum cursus. Donec vitae arcu varius, dapibus dolor ut, commodo arcu. Pellentesque consequat orci ex, id hendrerit ligula mollis vitae.

Suspendisse nulla libero, efficitur ut dapibus sed, commodo id enim. Cras bibendum urna in elementum egestas. Nulla a metus tincidunt, auctor ante non, pharetra arcu. Donec vitae efficitur enim. Fusce orci odio, scelerisque non vestibulum efficitur, fermentum ac velit. Nunc tincidunt ac lectus nec tincidunt. Sed consectetur semper lacus at posuere. Vestibulum blandit dolor at eros varius, quis euismod felis facilisis. Ut rutrum neque neque. Etiam vitae odio turpis. 
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: Why is the DIV absolutely positioned? It removes it from the flow, which is not what you want.

Comment: Actually, I want it to be there as an overlay type element so that when there is another block (dynamically) added  below it.

Comment: @Abnik Sorry, but to me that makes no sense. You either want it to overlay, or you want the content to go under it. Absolute positioning should be a last resort. Unless you can properly justify using it, there is probably a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: That's exactly why I was having a hard time writing the question. I want it overlayed, only to those elements that are added after (within the `<header>`) the absolutely positioned div, not to the content section.

Comment: Ah I see! That makes sense! In that case, your issue appears to be that there is no content initially in the header. I suggest adding a min-height to the site-header of around 100px.

Comment: Can you illustrate with the image what are you trying to achieve, I am sure it could be done with better html structure.

Comment: @DanishAdeel I am not sure how to illustrate this with image. Let me try narrating it to you. The `<header>` section and the `main-nav-wrapper` will be there all the time, but the `top-nav` and the element after `main-nav-wrapper` will be added dynamically based on user choice from backend within the `<header>`. I want the `main-nav-wrapper` to be overlayed to the last dynamically added element, if it's present. So, I need to clear the '<header>` properly so that it doesn't overlay the content section if the last dynamically added element isn't present.

Comment: @Abhik I have added an answer with fiddle, plaese check.

Answer (score 1):

You need to position to the `.content` section that will be displayed right after the absolutely positioned element:

```
.content{
   position: relative;
   top: 100px;
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j474js6e/2/)

Or, set the fixed height in `.site-header`:

```
.site-header{
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  display:block;
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j474js6e/4/)

Comment: Actually, I can't use a static value as top or margin because the height of the absolutely positioned div changes with the content within it.

Comment: I tested that, but it still overlapping if I add content to the absolutely positioned div.

Comment: @Abhik you need to set fixed height explicitly i.e. absolutely positioned div height...

Comment: Yeah, I guess I need to take another approach :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this [Fiddle with content](https://jsfiddle.net/j474js6e/6/)

```css
.site-header{
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  display:block;
}
.top-nav{
  background: #222222;
  padding:10px;
  display:block;
}
.main-nav-wrapper{
  position:relative;
  clear:both;
}
.overlay{
  position:absolute;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<header class="site-header">
  <nav class="top-nav">
  
  </nav>
  <div class="main-nav-wrapper">
    <nav class="overlay"></nav>
    <nav class="main-nav">home | about</nav>
    <p>
    More content
    </p>
  </div>
</header>
<section class="content">
  <h1>SECTION HEADING</h1>
  <p>
  

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin tortor ante, dictum sed volutpat sit amet, accumsan at urna. Vestibulum congue, nulla a mollis dapibus, ex ex iaculis velit, vel lacinia elit justo at erat. Nulla at rutrum ipsum. Integer et tortor vitae ligula porttitor feugiat. Quisque quis nulla in tortor eleifend aliquet.
  </p>
</section>
```

and [Fiddle without content](https://jsfiddle.net/j474js6e/7/),

```css
.site-header{
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  display:block;
}
.top-nav{
  background: #222222;
  padding:10px;
  display:block;
}
.main-nav-wrapper{
  position:relative;
  clear:both;
}
.overlay{
  position:absolute;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<header class="site-header">
  <nav class="top-nav">
  
  </nav>
  <div class="main-nav-wrapper">
    <nav class="overlay"></nav>
    <nav class="main-nav"></nav>
  </div>
</header>
<section class="content">
  <h1>SECTION HEADING</h1>
  <p>
  

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin tortor ante, dictum sed volutpat sit amet, accumsan at urna. Vestibulum congue, nulla a mollis dapibus, ex ex iaculis velit, vel lacinia elit justo at erat. Nulla at rutrum ipsum. Integer et tortor vitae ligula porttitor feugiat. Quisque quis nulla in tortor eleifend aliquet. Nunc nec dui nisl. 
  </p>
</section>
```

so now if there is a content the overlay will appear and if not than it will not show itself, I havnt added any fixed height to any element I have just added an addition div for overlay. Is that how you want ?

Answer (score 0):

it is because `<header>` does not have actual height, and you have navigation inside it which is cut out from document flow. either set height to `<header>` or don't use absolute positioning for navigation, otherwise `<header>` will colapse to height 0.

https://jsfiddle.net/j474js6e/3/ - height to header

https://jsfiddle.net/j474js6e/5/ - removed absolute from wrapper

Answer (score 0):

An absolute positioned div does not take any space in its parent element. So you can create space for example with a margin in the affected element that's as high as the absolute positioned element. In your case:

```
.content { margin-top: 120px; }
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ryup26kx/

Comment: Can't use static values there as the height of the absolutely positioned div varies with the content witin it

Comment: you can also use percentage values, but maybe the choice of absolute positioning is not so ideal for an element that can change size - I'd change it to relative. In your example the need for absolute position is not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `position:absolute;` in `.main-nav-wrapper`:

```css
.site-header{
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
.site-header::after{
  content:"";
  height:1px;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  clear:both;
}
.top-nav{
  background: #222222;
  padding:10px;
  display:block;
}
.main-nav-wrapper{
  XXXposition:absolute;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  padding:40px 0;
  height:20px;
  width:100%;
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<header class="site-header">
  <nav class="top-nav">
  
  </nav>
  <div class="main-nav-wrapper">
    <nav class="main-nav"></nav>
  </div>
</header>
<section class="content">
  <h1>SECTION HEADING</h1>
  <p>
  

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin tortor ante, dictum sed volutpat sit amet, accumsan at urna. Vestibulum congue, nulla a mollis dapibus, ex ex iaculis velit, vel lacinia elit justo at erat. Nulla at rutrum ipsum. Integer et tortor vitae ligula porttitor feugiat. Quisque quis nulla in tortor eleifend aliquet. Nunc nec dui nisl. Integer ultricies ullamcorper nisl, ut imperdiet augue luctus id. Proin lobortis non nibh ut accumsan. Sed mi ligula, suscipit non commodo vitae, facilisis at sapien. Praesent luctus arcu tincidunt felis consectetur volutpat. Duis tellus risus, auctor elementum bibendum at, varius vel massa. Etiam tristique sit amet nisi a vestibulum. Aenean mollis suscipit nunc. Vestibulum volutpat diam ut metus interdum cursus. Donec vitae arcu varius, dapibus dolor ut, commodo arcu. Pellentesque consequat orci ex, id hendrerit ligula mollis vitae.

Suspendisse nulla libero, efficitur ut dapibus sed, commodo id enim. Cras bibendum urna in elementum egestas. Nulla a metus tincidunt, auctor ante non, pharetra arcu. Donec vitae efficitur enim. Fusce orci odio, scelerisque non vestibulum efficitur, fermentum ac velit. Nunc tincidunt ac lectus nec tincidunt. Sed consectetur semper lacus at posuere. Vestibulum blandit dolor at eros varius, quis euismod felis facilisis. Ut rutrum neque neque. Etiam vitae odio turpis. 
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: Amm!! It needs to be absolutely positioned :(

Comment: But it isn't in your code. Anyway "relative" means absolute to the parent, try this: `position: relative;
top: 0px;`, same result

Answer (score 0):

```
 position:relative:
 top:0px:

 clear:both;
```

clear both for the lower div